# Do citizens of Monaco get an entry receipt when entering the UK on an ID card?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, monegasque-citizens

Citizens of Monaco don't enjoy freedom of movement in the UK, and may only stay visa-free for up to 6 months.

Nevertheless, according to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=mc&DE=gb&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), uniquely among non-EEA/Swiss nationals, they can enter on a national ID card.

Do Monaco ID card holders get some sort of receipt of their legal entry (like I as a Swede get in Turkey), or does the Home Office exclusively rely on electronic records to track their status in the UK?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94100/what-does-the-uk-immigration-form-is-116-look-like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to the Border Force at Heathrow T3 revealed, after lots of double and triple checking, that Monaco ID cards **are** accepted for the UK, and that an entry form **is** issued, and is called IS 116, which is meant to be presented in case of internal immigration checks.

However, the form was not issued in the only case known to me of this document being used.

Answer (score 2):

The question presumes that Citizens of Monaco can enter UK with an ID card.

[According to the Embassy of Monaco in the UK:](http://embassy-to-uk.gouv.mc/en/Information-and-Services/Visiting-UK)

> Only a valid Monegasque passport is recognised as an official document by the UK Border Agency (UKBA). Monegasques are considered as non-EU citizens and cannot enter the country freely.

Furthermore, the United Kingdom [list of accepted travel documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/what-are-acceptable-travel-documents-for-entry-clearance-ecb08/ecb08-what-are-acceptable-travel-documents-for-entry-clearance) makes no exceptions for Citizens of Monaco being able to enter with an ID card. So a better question might be, if the information of IATA is valid and if Monegasque citizens can actually enter the UK with an ID card.

One big difference in the comparison to Turkey though, is that the UK has no border control while exiting the country. Presuming that the point of the receipt is to prove, that you haven't overstayed as exiting the country, what would be the point?

Comment: The Timatic team recently told me that their government sources recently confirmed to them that Monaco ID cards are still valid. They also told me that actual practice at the border frequently differs from formal law.

Comment: "Presuming that the point of the receipt is to prove, that you haven't overstayed as exiting the country, what would be the point?" By that logic, passport stamps are also redundant. Also, police/Immigration enforcement checks inside the country are not uncommon