# What does the UK immigration form IS 116 look like?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

I just found out that the UK issues an entry form at ports of entry for holders of non-EEA travel documents that cannot be endorsed, called IS 116.

What does this form look like? Couldn't find any images on the web.

Comment: @JonathanReez he probably wants to know what info it asks for so he can make sure of it and remember it before traveling and having to fill the form out.

Comment: @JoelDamien but the form is supposedly given out by immigration, not filled out by the traveler

Comment: @JonathanReez Joel is correct. My Monegasque friend got no such thing when entering the UK, so I want him to be able to ask for and recognise it next time (in case he's stopped by the IE)

Comment: Google knows nothing about this form. Where did you hear about it?

Comment: What do you mean "non-EEA travel documents that cannot be endorsed"? Ones that you can't put an entry stamp in?

Comment: @DJClayworth Correct. The Border Force at Heathrow told me about it on the phone, as I asked how nationals of Monaco are processed when entering on an ID card (the only nationality without freedom of movement that can use them). Could've been IS - unsure about the second consonant - but IF=Immigration form makes more sense

Comment: @Crazydre however *IS* could stand for "Immigration Service," and apparently it does. I found a reference to form IS 116 at https://www.immigrationboards.com/post65037.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the front of the form (obtained through a FOI request to the Home Office).

[image: 1]

The leave conditions are stated on the rear side of the form, with the stamp being placed at the bottom right corner of the rear side.

Comment: The FOI request sent you a photo of the form?